# Are DSLContext objects heavy in JOOQ?

Tags: java, jooq

I'm writing a web service. I want to know if [`DSLContext`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html) object is heavy to create? Can I create them inside DAO methods(and destroy them when method finished) or It is better to create one when request starts and pass it to DAO classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DSLContext` itself is just a wrapper for [`Configuration`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Configuration.html) with lots of DSL methods in it.

The `Configuration` itself is again a wrapper for your JDBC `Connection` / `DataSource`, [`Settings`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html), [`SQLDialect`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html), and other SPI implementations that you may choose to add. So, in other words, the effort of creating a new `DSLContext` instance is negligible, as you're only wrapping other objects that you already have.

See also these sections of the jOOQ manual:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/performance-considerations/